# RDP-подключение из linux с указанием TSG-сервера

Tags: linux, windows, rdp, поиск-программ

Нужно из Linux Mint подключиться по rdp к Windows 7.

Установил Remmina и плагин для rdp к нему.

Но мне нужно при подключении указать tsg-сервер - не пойму, где это можно сделать.

PS: [Этот вопрос на английском.](//askubuntu.com/q/738703/511165)

Answer (score 1):

Как понимаю из документации на TSG, Remmina не сможет (пока что) подключиться на порт 443 с помощью HTTP-туннеля SSL/TLS, как реализовано в сервере TSG.
 Только SSH-туннелирование с пробросом порта до нужного АРМ в рабочей сети.

Comment: А какой клиент умеет? А вообще, странно, что само по себе rdp она умеет (там отдельный пакет), а именно tsg нет?

Comment: Честно - не знаю пока. А насчет TSG - это же шлюз для RDP, а не сам по себе RDP. Т.е. RDP-подключение происходит внутри HTTP-туннеля. Вот создавать данный туннель Remmina пока не умеет, возможно добавят в последующих версиях.